# Is there a python code that I can add to my program that will add it to start in windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

Currently, I have been scouring the internet for a code that will either add this program (something.exe) to the windows task scheduler or if that is not even an option how to add it to the windows reg key for a startup. I cannot find anything in terms of Python3, and I really hope it is not an answer that is right in front of my face. Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify. You are trying to have a python script execute as an .exe using the windows task scheduler?

Comment: Just go to the start menu and run Task Scheduler? Or do you want to set it up programatically?

Comment: using `winreg` library to access window startup registry

Comment: @tdelaney I want to set it up programatically, but I am not sure if thats possible

Comment: @B-hads - Yes, you can do it through python's win32 api (search "python win32 task scheduler"), python WMI (search "python wmi task scheduler" or paw through Tim Golden's [WMI cookbook](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#wmi-cookbook) or even by using `subprocess` to run WMIC from the command line. It'll take a bit of work to figure out, but there are examples. Its common to see VB or C# examples that need to be "pythonized".

Answer (score 0):

Open the windows scheduler -> select "create basic task" -> fill out the desired times -> input the path to the script you want to execute.